# php curl login to espn.com

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

Im trying so many different things and not finding any solution, in order to login using cUrl to http://www.espn.com/login/ and after login i want to retrieve a protected password area http://games.espn.com/ffl/clubhouse?leagueId=93772&teamId=1&seasonId=2018

what i have try to use is this:

```
$username = 'email';
$password = 'password!';
$loginUrl = 'http://www.espn.com/login/';

//init curl
$ch = curl_init();

//Set the URL to work with
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $loginUrl);

// ENABLE HTTP POST
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

//Set the post parameters
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'user='.$username.'&pass='.$password);

//Handle cookies for the login
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');

//Setting CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER variable to 1 will force cURL
//not to print out the results of its query.
//Instead, it will return the results as a string return value
//from curl_exec() instead of the usual true/false.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

//execute the request (the login)
$store = curl_exec($ch);

//the login is now done and you can continue to get the
//protected content.
sleep(3);
//set the URL to the protected file
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://games.espn.com/ffl/clubhouse?leagueId=93772&teamId=1&seasonId=2018');

//execute the request
$content = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

//save the data to disk
file_put_contents('download.txt', $content);
```

but again is not retrieving the html after script login!

Comment: That's not how the ESPN login works. You can't just assume the fields are named user and pass and then POST into them with plain text. If you open your network log panel, you'll see there are multiple AJAX hits to a registration URL that uses JSON. (And probably some JS hurdles to prevent you from doing what you're trying.) You'll probably find it extremely difficult if not impossible to scrape this data.

Comment: yes you are probably right, i can't find even the link where to make the call. Maybe that is the issue. Correct?

Comment: You can find the link in the details recorded by the network panel in your browser's dev tools, but that's likely not going to help you much.

Comment: do you see any solution at this? or is impossible

Comment: "You'll probably find it extremely difficult if not impossible to scrape this data."

Comment: You're likely better off looking to see if they have an API to access the data you want.

Comment: Thanks, i appreciate

Comment: that login page use JSON to login, but your code try to login with a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`-format  (which is even improperly sanitized!) , no wonder your code doesn't work

Comment: when dedicating a project, there is always a solution!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the login procedure of this page is ***far*** more complicated than your code makes it out to be, also, this is highly unusual, this is the first website login system i've seen that doesn't use cookies (which is the near-universal way to do it) -  here's how to log in:

1: send an `OPTIONS` request to `https://registerdisney.go.com/jgc/v6/client/ESPN-ONESITE.WEB-PROD/api-key?langPref=en-US` with the headers `Access-Control-Request-Method: POST` and `Access-Control-Request-Headers: cache-control,content-type,conversation-id,correlation-id,expires,pragma` and `Origin: https://cdn.registerdisney.go.com` , 
it will respond with a header looking like `correlation-id: 13fb884f-d873-4344-9f32-fdeaa64cec7c`, you must parse out and save this correlation-id header.

2: this gets tricky, you need to generate a `conversation-id`, i extracted the generation algorithm for you, it was hidden deep in minified js, it is generated by the uuid function, which goes as follows:

```
function f() { return g() + g() + "-" + g() + "-" + g("4") + "-" + g((Math.floor(10 * Math.random()) % 4 + 8).toString(16)) + "-" + g() + g() + g() }

function g(e) { for (var t = Math.floor(65535 * Math.random()).toString(16), n = 4 - t.length; n > 0; n--) t = "0" + t; return e = ("" + e).substring(0, 4), !isNaN(parseInt(e, 16)) && e.length ? e + t.substr(e.length) : t }

function uuid(){return f();}
```

(and because you're running PHP, not javascript, you must convert this code to PHP. it is rather trivial if you know both javascript and PHP, i cba atm), the output looks something like `conversation-id: e2e3b494-2b67-4fe1-b0a2-21e0f7fa84ff`, when it is generated, save it. now send a POST request to `https://registerdisney.go.com/jgc/v6/client/ESPN-ONESITE.WEB-PROD/api-key?langPref=en-US` with the request body literally containing the string `null`, and with the headers `Referer: https://cdn.registerdisney.go.com/v2/ESPN-ONESITE.WEB-PROD/en-US?include=config,l10n,js,html&scheme=http&postMessageOrigin=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.espn.com%2Flogin%2F&cookieDomain=www.espn.com&config=PROD&logLevel=LOG&topHost=www.espn.com&cssOverride=https%3A%2F%2Fsecure.espncdn.com%2Fcombiner%2Fc%3Fcss%3Ddisneyid%2Fcore.css&responderPage=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.espn.com%2Flogin%2Fresponder%2F&buildId=16388ed5943` and `Content-Type: application/json` and `conversation-id: $conversation_id` and `correlation-id: $correlation_id` (and note, the referer-header is hardcoded and fake, you are not redirected to this url, but the javascript code is written to fake it to make it look like it was a redirect. weird shit, right?)

the response will contain an `api-key` header, looking something like `api-key: MR6UpmRG0VAqAvKStLzof79sbb+1w/HHBextDPqktXf9eXoDfklhgRMFKBpOqt5j63AqoYFx0VHH7/eePYnuw9U7Rg1F`, you must parse out and save this api key.

3: do an OPTIONS request to `https://ha.registerdisney.go.com/jgc/v6/client/ESPN-ONESITE.WEB-PROD/guest/login?langPref=en-US HTTP/1.1` with the headers `Access-Control-Request-Method: POST` and `Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization,cache-control,content-type,conversation-id,correlation-id,expires,pragma` and `Origin: https://cdn.registerdisney.go.com`

note: it will give you a new correlation-id token in a header, but ignore it, it doesn't seem to be used anywhere, the old correlation-token is the 1 you're supposed to keep using for the next request.

4: do a POST request to `https://ha.registerdisney.go.com/jgc/v6/client/ESPN-ONESITE.WEB-PROD/guest/login?langPref=en-US`, the body must be json-encoded with the username and password, and it looks like `json_encode(array('loginValue'=>$username,'password'=>$password))`, with the headers `Referer: https://cdn.registerdisney.go.com/v2/ESPN-ONESITE.WEB-PROD/en-US?include=config,l10n,js,html&scheme=http&postMessageOrigin=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.espn.com%2Flogin%2F&cookieDomain=www.espn.com&config=PROD&logLevel=LOG&topHost=www.espn.com&cssOverride=https%3A%2F%2Fsecure.espncdn.com%2Fcombiner%2Fc%3Fcss%3Ddisneyid%2Fcore.css&responderPage=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.espn.com%2Flogin%2Fresponder%2F&buildId=16388ed5943` and `Content-Type: application/json` and `Authorization: APIKEY $api_key` (note, you must literally start it with the uppercase string APIKEY, followed by a space and the actual api key you extracted earlier) and `correlation-id: $correlation_id` and `conversation-id: $conversation_id` and `Origin: https://cdn.registerdisney.go.com`

here it responds with a json, presumably, if the login is successful, the `error` member of the json is empty, but for example, when the username does not exist, the error object contains, among other things, the following: 
`Error: invalid_grant, Description: 'PROFILE.NOT_FOUND', Code: AUTHENTICATION_FAILED"}`

(meaning the username i used, `foo`, does not exist.)

if the login was now successful, i assume it gives you a token or cookie that you can give to http://games.espn.com/ffl/clubhouse?leagueId=93772&teamId=1&seasonId=2018 to check the page as logged in, but since i don't have a valid username/password to test with, i can't actually confirm this.

Comment: Let's wait and see how long it takes until they change a little piece of their algorithm ;)

Comment: @NicoHaase they changed it close to 2020-09-14, meaning the instructions above worked for ~26.3 months / 2.2 years! not bad for a hack of this complexity

Comment: Did you actually use this method during that time? Have you figured out how to make it work again? I used Dev Tools to inspect the requests that the official website makes but replicating it doesn't work for me. I always get `FAILURE_BY_DESIGN`, `AUTHORIZATION_CREDENTIALS`, reason `PALOMINO_CHECK_FAILED`. I'm suspicious of the `g-recaptcha-token` header sent to `/guest/login`, do you remember whether that was present when you had it working? That's the only part that I was copying from the website's request.

Comment: @SeanHall i never used it myself, but iirc i helped user https://stackoverflow.com/users/8662034/falcorthedog  make it work again around 2020-09-14, he might have working code to login, i don't recall fighting with recaptcha though. (and i don't remember exactly what i had to do to make it work)

Comment: @SeanHall PS if you need the code and have a budget, i can probably fix it again for $200

Comment: No I don't need code, my backup plan is the activation code workflow for getting a token from https://github.com/t43pasdf/plugin.video.espn_3. I would prefer getting the token without any chance of user interaction, but I suspect they tried to remove that possibility by adding the recaptcha. If someone like @falcorthedog has working code then I'd love to hear that it is possible.

Comment: @SeanHall did you ever get this working? I'm also getting the palomino check failed, also tried copying from the site but same error

Comment: I had to get the login token through the activation code workflow that I mentioned above instead of sending a POST request to /guest/login.

Comment: Ah okay, so there was  user interaction?

Comment: Yes, there is user interaction for them to activate the code. But after that there is no interaction required for a while because the login token you get will be valid for 6 months.